# swi prolog is executing all readln before any write

Tags: prolog

In my code, it seems that all `readln` statements are executed before a single `write` is done. 
My code :

```
go :- readln(A), write(A), readln(B), write(B).
```

How it currently run

```
? go.
|: foo
bar
[foo][bar]
true.
```

But i want

```
? go.
|: foo
[foo]
bar
[bar]
true.
```

Any idea what might cause that behavior and how to change it?

Comment: what is readln ?

Comment: @CapelliC it's predefined in swi-prolog http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/readln.pl

Comment: yes, it's deprecated and undocumented... better to use read_line_to_codes/2

Comment: The issue is caused by the fact that write/1 does not flush the output.  Either use e.g., writeln/1 or use an explicit call to flush_output/0.

Comment: @CapelliC unfortunately the teacher force me to use readln :(

Comment: @JanWielemaker thanks, that worked! Feel free to post that as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I'm not much into collecting points and I think the answer of @CapelliC is good.  You teacher shouldn't ask using old deprecated predicates, on the terminal you typically want to write lines and as read_line_to_codes/2 returns a list of character codes, using format/2 is the most appropriate way to print its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CapelliC suggested:

```
?- listing(go).
go :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, A),
    format("~s~n", [A]),
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, B),
    format("~s~n", [B]).

true.

?- go.
|    foo
foo
|    bar
bar
true.
```